# Opening link in WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an application at the moment that basically opens a url depending on what the user has typed into a textbox. The logic for this is as such:

```
Predetermined beginning + User Input + Predetermined End
```

So basically my URL is 3 concatenated strings. Now I know the link is being formed properly (I've put the same snip of code into a label) but nothing happens when I press the button to load the webview.

It works perfectly fine when I use the below, where I explicitly type https://google.com

```
- (IBAction)btnSearchPress:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL  = @"https://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_wbView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

However nothing happens when I use this code which includes my concatenated url:

```
- (IBAction)btnSearchPress:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _urlPrefix.text,_txtInput.text, _urlSuffix.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_wbView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE: I'm fairly sure having the stringWithFormat is causing this problem just unsure how to get around it.**:

Comment: What's contained in `fullURL` after you've set it? Can you show us the output of `NSLog(fullURL)`?

Comment: The string is properly formed, it spits out the URL I'd expect, which I've tested and it works. I had it printing it out in a label too whilst trying to figure it out to make sure.

Comment: Ok, with a breakpoint at NSURLRequest it's telling me url is nill. Baffled.

Comment: You are still not showing us the actual strings being used to form the URL. Clearly the result is not a valid URL string. You are asking for help but you are hiding the key facts.

Comment: The URL probably doesn't being with `http:` or it has spaces.

Comment: As I said in the original post, I have tested the link and it's fine. That's not the issue. *url remains nill when I use stringWithFormat.

Here is my NSLog output for fullURL

2014-04-25 21:41:09.108 MessingAround[4926:60b]

 https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=1323 intitle:"index.of" "parent directory" "size" "last modified" "description" [snd] (mp4|mp3|avi) -inurl:(jsp|php|html|aspx|htm|cf|shtml|lyrics|mp3s|mp3|index) -gallery -intitle:"last modified" -intitle:(intitle|mp3)

Comment: So your log output proves what we have said. The URL doesn't begin with http and it has spaces. Both are bad.

Comment: It does. Stack changed it to remove the https:\\ though, I'm not an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if fullURL starts with http:// or https://, if not prefix that.

```
- (IBAction)btnSearchPress:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _urlPrefix.text,_txtInput.text, _urlSuffix.text];

    if ( ! ([fullURL hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [ fullURL hasPrefix:@"https://"]) ) {
     fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", fullURL ];
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_wbView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: Appropriate the answer but it's unnecessary this way. the URL prefix is hard-coded so always has a https:// prefix.

Comment: What does NSLog of fullURL show? It did not print out clearly in the comments under the original post.

Comment: It's a fullly functioning lin, sorry stack automatically removed the https:// part